# C# arraylist user input

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a problem with ArrayList in C#, I know how can I add my own input and run the program so the Array is filled with information. But I would like to fill an ArrayList based on user input.

This is what I need: the user could enter his/hers name, birthdate and age. And all these theree information would be stored in one element.

My goal is to be able to make an application which would allow the user to enter this kind of data for several people and then print the output.

Here is my code:

I have a class Person which handles the user information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ArrayList_Siomple_Sorted_10
{
    class Person
    {
    private string personName;
    private DateTime birthDate;
    private double personAge;

    public Person(string name, DateTime bDate, double age)
    {
        personName = name;
        birthDate = bDate;
        personAge = age;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return personName; }
        set { personName = value; }
    }
    public DateTime Birthdate
    {
        get { return birthDate; }
        set { birthDate = value; }
    }

    public double Grade
    {
        get { return personAge; }
        set { personAge = value; }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(personName + " " + birthDate.ToString("d.M.yyyy") + " " + personAge);
    }
}
}
```

And this is the Main class with main method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

namespace ArrayList_Siomple_Sorted_10
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime birthDateP3 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
        Person p3 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP3, 8);
        DateTime birthDateP2 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
        Person p2 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP2, 8);
        DateTime birthDateP1 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
        Person p1 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP1, 8);

        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

        ar.Add(p1);
        ar.Add(p2);
        ar.Add(p3);
        Console.WriteLine("Print the original Array");
        foreach (Person pr in ar)
            pr.Show();

    }
}
}
```

Is the thing I am trying to achieve even possible? Thank you for your answers.
V.

Comment: If your instructor is using `ArrayList`s, then he needs to step into 2005 and get into generics.

Comment: You need to get input from the user, so look as Console.Read... Then you need to turn the string they enter into the types for the properties on you Person object, the rest you have already done. You may want to look at List<T> rather than array list but it rather depends on how far you are through your course. Also look at auto properties, which will save you some typing. Also find anyone's coding standards and read them, there's plenty on-line.

Comment: You'll need some kind of UI for that, for example WinForms, WPF or WebForms.

Comment: @kaze A console application is a UI.

Comment: @joeenos Maybe the next chapter uses `List<>` and asks for the differences...

Comment: @JoeEnos Yes I know, I could not read that from the original question, so I figured that to answer the question, it would be important to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's possible. What is the exact issue that are you facing here?
BTW, instead of `ArrayList`, you should be using generic collection `List<Person>`.

From console program, you will use `Console.ReadLine` to get user input, validate/parse it and fill person instance and add  to your list. For example,

```
...
    var ar = new List<Person>();

    var name = Console.ReadLine();
    // validate name (check if its not blank string etc)
    ...

    var dob = Console.ReadLine();
    // validate date of birth (date/time format, past date etc)
    ...
    DateTime dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(dob);

    // compute age
    var age = (DateTime.Now - dateOfBirth).Years;

    var p = new Person(name, dateOfBirth, age);
    ar.Add(p);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should consider using `List<T>` instead of ArrayList.

Secondly, off course, this is possible. You can do it in the following way.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime birthDateP3 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
    Person p3 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP3, 8);
    DateTime birthDateP2 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
    Person p2 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP2, 8);
    DateTime birthDateP1 = new DateTime(1980, 2, 25);
    Person p1 = new Person("Ann Person", birthDateP1, 8);

    ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();

    string name = Console.ReadLine();        
    ar.Add(name);


    Console.WriteLine("Print the original Array");
    foreach (Person pr in ar)
        pr.Show();

}
```

And you should be using Generic list instead of `ArrayList` like this:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
string str = Console.ReadLine();
mylist.Add(str);
```

Comment: List is a nice thing, but I am supposed to make it using the ArrayList. But in the Main class I need that the users in the console his name, birthdate and age. So, the will be no DateTime birthDateP3 = etc. Only the input from the user. When the user inputs: Max Payne, 25.5.2005, 6 then this info will be stored in the first object of the arraylist.

Comment: @Vojtech: ArrayList shouldn't be used now since it has a hugely better alternative in the form of Generic List. If you are forced to do so, try finding a better instructor.

Comment: Finding a better instructor would be a great idea, but unfortunately it is not my vote and I have to make this his way :/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can read input data using Console.ReadLine() method or if you want a more sophisticated interface you can use Windows Form API.